# Hide Bottom Status Bar from JQuery Multiselect

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-multiselect

I set up my multiselect dropdown with Bootstap, but bottom status bar is distrub the UX thing, can someone figure out how to turn off it?

[image: SS of Bottom Status Bar]

This is the config of Bootstap multiselect

```
 var config = {
        enableFiltering: true,
        enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
        includeSelectAllOption: true,
        maxWidth: 400,
        maxHeight: 200,
        scrollX: true,
        numberDisplayed: 1
    }
```

can someone figure out how to turn off it?

Comment: can you please elaborate more about your problem, it is still unclear. thanks

Comment: whn i pointing at dropdown, it will show status bar browser in the corner bottom, look like in screen shoot, like showing what value i selected